# Error in the header file of blob class (openCV library)

Tags: opencv, blob, header-files

I am using the blob library from openCV and I have included all the requred libraries for that .. but I am getting red lines under some function in Blob.cpp class .. these are:

```
CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM( edgeactual, reader);
CV_WRITE_SEQ_ELEM( edgeactual, writer );
```

I tried to include all the possible headers in that class with no use. if anyone has previously dealt with blob library from opencv would be greatly helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the **error log** it would be really helpfull, and if you can print screenshots of the includes and libraries of your IDE (I guess VisualStudio or Eclipse). These kind of errors are usually due to

the environment variable #PATH 
the includes
the libraries

I had to deal with these errors many times and even I thought I had everything right it is easy to link a library wrongly with openCV.